Troubleshooting Poor Audio Quality in WASAPI Loopback Recording
I am attempting to use WASAPI for loopback recording, but the recorded WAV audio has significantly lower sound quality compared to the original audio being captured. The sound differs noticeably, and I’ve been unable to find a solution to resolve this issue.
// Record.h
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <audioclient.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
#define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000

#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)  \
              if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }
// 定义WAV文件头部结构
struct WAVHeader {
    char chunkID[4];        // 文件标识，通常为"RIFF"
    uint32_t chunkSize;     // 文件大小
    char format[4];         // 文件格式，“WAVE”
    char subchunk1ID[4];    // 子块标识，“fmt”
    uint32_t subchunk1Size; // 子块大小
    uint16_t audioFormat;   // 音频格式，1为PCM格式
    uint16_t numChannels;   // 声道数，1:单声道，2:双声道
    uint32_t sampleRate;    // 采样率
    uint32_t byteRate;      // 每秒的字节数
    uint16_t blockAlign;    // 块对齐
    uint16_t bitsPerSample; // 采样深度
    char subchunk2ID[4];    // 子块标识，“data”
    uint32_t subchunk2Size; // 子块大小
};
// 音频数据结构
struct WAVData {
    struct WAVHeader header;  // 音频头部数据
    uint8_t* sample;          // 音频数据
};

class WAVWriter {
public:
    WAVWriter(const char* filename, WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx)
        : file(filename, std::ios::binary), totalDataSize(0) {

        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open file for writing\n";
            return;
        }

        // 初始化 WAV 头
        memcpy(wavData.header.chunkID, "RIFF", 4);
        memcpy(wavData.header.format, "WAVE", 4);
        memcpy(wavData.header.subchunk1ID, "fmt ", 4);
        wavData.header.subchunk1Size = 16;
        wavData.header.audioFormat = 1;
        memcpy(wavData.header.subchunk2ID, "data", 4);
        // 暂时写入空白头，稍后更新
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&wavData.header), sizeof(wavData.header));
    }
    void updateHeader(WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx) {
        wavData.header.numChannels = pwfx->nChannels;
        wavData.header.sampleRate = pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;
        wavData.header.bitsPerSample = pwfx->wBitsPerSample;
        wavData.header.byteRate = pwfx->nSamplesPerSec * pwfx->nChannels * pwfx->wBitsPerSample / 8;
        wavData.header.blockAlign = pwfx->nChannels * pwfx->wBitsPerSample / 8;
    }
    void WriteData(BYTE* pData, UINT32 dataSize) {
        if (!file.is_open()) return;

        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pData), dataSize);
        totalDataSize += dataSize;
    }

    void Finalize() {
        if (!file.is_open()) return;

        // 填写 WAV 头的最终大小信息
        wavData.header.chunkSize = 36 + totalDataSize;  // 36 是 WAV 头部的大小减去文件头的前8字节
        wavData.header.subchunk2Size=totalDataSize;
        wavData.sample = new uint8_t[totalDataSize];

        // 回到文件开始位置，写入更新后的头
        file.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&wavData.header), sizeof(wavData.header));
        std::cout << std::string(wavData.header.chunkID, 4) << " chunkID\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.chunkSize << " chunkSize\n";
        std::cout << std::string(wavData.header.format, 4) << " format\n";
        std::cout << std::string(wavData.header.subchunk1ID, 4) << " subchunk1ID\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.subchunk1Size << " subchunk1Size\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.audioFormat << " audioFormat\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.numChannels << " numChannels\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.sampleRate << " sampleRate\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.byteRate << " byteRate\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.blockAlign << " blockAlign\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.bitsPerSample << " bitsPerSample\n";
        std::cout << std::string(wavData.header.subchunk2ID, 4) << " subchunk2ID\n";
        std::cout << wavData.header.subchunk2Size << " subchunk2Size\n";
        file.close();
    }

private:
    std::ofstream file;
    WAVData wavData;
    uint32_t totalDataSize;
};


class MyAudioSink {
public:
    MyAudioSink(const char* outputFile) : wavWriter(outputFile, nullptr) {}

    void SetFormat(WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx) {
        std::cout << "Audio format set: " << pwfx->nChannels << " channels, "
            << pwfx->nSamplesPerSec << " Hz\n";

        wavWriter = WAVWriter("output.wav", pwfx);  // 初始化 WAV 文件写入
    }
    void updateHeader(WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx) {
        wavWriter.updateHeader(pwfx);
    }
    HRESULT CopyData(BYTE* pData, UINT32 numFramesAvailable, WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx, BOOL* bDone) {
        std::cout << "Received " << numFramesAvailable << " frames\n";


        if (numFramesAvailable > 0) {
            if (pData != NULL) {
                // 计算数据的字节数
                UINT32 dataSize = numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign; // 根据音频格式动态计算
                wavWriter.WriteData(pData, dataSize);
            }
            else {
                // pData 为 NULL，处理静音情况
                std::cout << "Received NULL pData, writing silence.\n";
                UINT32 dataSize = numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign; // 计算需要写入的字节数
                BYTE* silenceData = new BYTE[dataSize]; // 动态分配内存用于静音数据
                memset(silenceData, 0, dataSize); // 用零填充静音数据

                wavWriter.WriteData(silenceData, dataSize); // 写入静音数据
                delete[] silenceData; // 释放内存
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "No frames available to process.\n";
        }
        return S_OK;
    }

    void Finalize() {
        wavWriter.Finalize();  // 录制完成后更新文件头
    }

private:
    WAVWriter wavWriter;
};


#include <windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <audioclient.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Record.h"

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IAudioClient = __uuidof(IAudioClient);
const IID IID_IAudioCaptureClient = __uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient);

HRESULT RecordAudioStream(MyAudioSink* pMySink) {
    HRESULT hr;
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration;
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
    UINT32 numFramesAvailable;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioClient* pAudioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient* pCaptureClient = NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = NULL;
    UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    BOOL bDone = FALSE;
    BYTE* pData;
    DWORD flags;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (void**)&pEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        // 获取默认的音频渲染设备
       hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);
      // hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &pDevice);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
        std::cout << pDevice;
        hr = pDevice->Activate(IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        // 初始化为共享模式，启用环回
        hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK, hnsRequestedDuration, 0, pwfx, NULL);
        //hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, hnsRequestedDuration, 0, pwfx, NULL);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = pAudioClient->GetService(IID_IAudioCaptureClient, (void**)&pCaptureClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        pMySink->SetFormat(pwfx);

    hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC * bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;

    hr = pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
        pMySink->updateHeader(pwfx);
        while (!bDone) {
            Sleep(hnsActualDuration / REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC / 2);
            hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

                while (packetLength != 0) {
                    hr = pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &numFramesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL);
                    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

                        if (flags & AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT) {
                            pData = NULL;  // Tell CopyData to write silence.
                        }

                    hr = pMySink->CopyData(pData, numFramesAvailable, pwfx, &bDone);
                    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

                        hr = pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
                    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

                        hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
                    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
                }

            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)) {

                bDone = TRUE;  // 停止录制
            }
        }

    hr = pAudioClient->Stop();  // Stop recording.
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        Exit:
    CoTaskMemFree(pwfx);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioClient)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pCaptureClient)

        return hr;
}

int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    MyAudioSink audioSink("output.wav");
    HRESULT hr = RecordAudioStream(&audioSink);
    audioSink.Finalize();
    CoUninitialize();
    return hr == S_OK ? 0 : 1;
}


I attempted to use WASAPI for loopback recording, expecting the captured WAV audio to maintain the same quality as the original sound source. However, the resulting audio had significantly degraded quality, with noticeable differences in clarity and fidelity, which I had not anticipated.

is the AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT path actually happening?

Your recorded audio is actually perfectly fine. It's just the WAV header that's messed up somehow. Just tested with your code, then rename output.wav to output.raw and load that up in Audacity or any audio editing software that lets you load a raw audio file and manually select how to interpret it. In my case that got me a clean 32-bit float, stereo 48khz audio file.
I haven't digged in any further to see what's wrong with the wav header. Might be writing WAVEFORMATEX where WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE is expected, or vice-versa, or just incorrectly filling out some of the fields.
